# turn off unescaping in SAXParser

Tags: java, saxparser

I am using SAXParser in Java.

Is there a way to turn off unescaping while parsing xml using SAXParser?

For example I have the following xml:

```
<tag>
    &#8222;title&#8221;
</tag>
```

I would like to obtain by *characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)* message `&#8222;title&#8221;`

but the handler unescapes content of the xml and gives:
`„title”`

I tried with specifying custom EntityResolver, but it seems that resolveEntity() method never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAXParser is doing what it is supposed to do but if you want to preserve a text node as-is you need to wrap it in a CDATA section. You can either do this as a preprocess step or perhaps there is a way to do the wrapping while parsing (but I don't know how).